# How does iFrame traffic work?

Tags: html, iframe, https

If I put an iframe in document A pointing to document B, does document B reach me *through* the server hosting document A, or are both documents sent directly to me?
Following from this, if HTTPS is enabled for the server hosting document A but not the server hosting document B, is B encrypted before it is sent to me?

Answer (score 3):

When using an `<iframe>`, it is very similar to loading a complete browser window instance inside of another. The `<iframe>` can have its own sessions, cookies, etc. that are independent of the parent browser window.

If the parent page is delivered via HTTPS, it has no effect on how the `<iframe>` contained in the page is loaded (encrypted or not). Example: if you have a `https://` page that contains an `<iframe>` with an address of `http://`, that content will be loaded in the clear (not encrypted).

[Checkout this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) on `<iframe>`'s from MDN - it documents this element in great detail.

Also - `<iframe>`'s are relics of browsers from the 90's, so avoid using them if at all possible. They present all sorts of issues, especially with security and responsive design, so try to go with another option if possible.

Comment: This is very old, but I landed here from a Gag search. I have developed way back then and a little today, some PHP which I don't use (any more) because it's not as great as Javascript native from the 90's. What would you use instead of <iframe>? I'm wondering if dynamic "snippets" can be embedded into a website that people can use to put into their own site what will change on their page when I change my content or make corrections on my website. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is accessing both. The iframe is simply saying "go get this too", not retrieving the content for you. For that reason, HTTPS will not carry over to protect document B, it will be HTTP traffic and unencrypted.